# ARM shellcode for linux - svc 0 vs svc 1

Tags: arm, shellcode

Checking out Linux `ARM` shellcode I see that the system call is made by using the `svc 1` instruction. However, I have also seen [examples](http://brnz.org/hbr/?m=201102) where they use `svc 0` as the instruction that calls the system call.

Evidently, system calls in Linux on `ARM` can be performed using both `svc 0` and `svc 1`. Why is this the case as opposed to architectures such as `x86`. Are the kind of interrupts generated by both these instructions the same?

Comment: It's the same interrupt. The #imm parameter part (0, 1 etc) is ignored by Linux IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you should check [this](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0179b/ar01s02s07.html) part of the `ARM` documentation, and [this](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cihidabi.html) description of `svc` and its parameters. By cross referencing the two links you'll find an answer to your question.

From the links above you'll be able to understand what the parameter of the `svc` instruction represents. It is supposed to be ignored by the `CPU` but the exception handler can use that parameter to determine the service being requested : `ARM` instruction if the value is between 0 & 16777215, or `Thumb` instruction if the value is between 0 & 255.

The thumb instruction set is a compact 16bit encoding for ARM instructions. It was mainly designed & implemented for compact code-density. You can check the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Thumb#Thumb) page about the `ARM` architecture for more information, but I would recommend you going through the `ARM` documentation for accurate technical details.

Comment: could you add a short answer derived from those links ?

Comment: Here we go :done !